# How to conditionally create a serializer and sequence? (Option<SerializeSeq>)

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to process data from a channel, so the whole structure can't be serialized at once. In fact it won't all fit in memory. The trouble I'm running into is that I can't create an `Option<SerializeSeq>` because that object depends on `Serializer` (which doesn't live long enough). I'd like to initialize them both together, or not at all:

```
use serde::ser::{SerializeSeq, Serializer};
fn process_stream(output: bool) -> serde_json::Result<()> {
    let rows = /* whatever iterator */ "serde".chars();

    let mut seq = if output {
        let out = std::io::stdout();
        let mut ser = serde_json::Serializer::new(out);
        let seq = ser.serialize_seq(None)?
        Some(Ok(seq))
    } else {
        None
    }.transpose()?;

    for row in rows {
        //process_data(row);
        if let Some(seq) = &mut seq {
            seq.serialize_element(&row)?;
        }
    }

    if let Some(seq) = seq {
        seq.end()?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

(Original code snippet from [here](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/345).)

The problem is: `ser does not live long enough`. But I don't want to initialize `ser` in the outer scope because it may not be enabled (and its writer would create or truncate a file that should not be created). I tried returning `ser` and `seq` as a tuple. I tried putting them together in a helper struct, but I couldn't figure out all the template parameters and lifetimes.

How can serde serializer and sequence be initialized based on a condition and stored in `Option`?

Comment: Don't know if you tried that, but the obvious idea is to _declare_ `ser` in the outer scope, but initialize it only as needed: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b65b3f44a215f8c8652d2e1f7051c8ad

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you, I didn't realize that was allowed!

Comment: Even if it weren't, you could still fake it with `let mut ser = None` followed by `ser = Some(Serializer::new(...))`, and used as `ser.unwrap().serialize_element(&row)`. That would be uglier because it would require a misleading `unwrap()` that could in reality never trigger.

Comment: @user4815162342 I tried something like that, both that code and a more idiomatic version that used `map` or `if let`. It didn't work, but I may not have written it exactly as you have in mind... there are multiple ways this type of code can fail. In addition to a variable not living long enough, I'm not allowed to construct `seq` with a reference to a local variable. Or a function parameter. Or a temporary can be dropped while borrowing.

Comment: [This is](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=66c77f8e39f30794156445108fd99010) what I had in mind. You're allowed to construct `seq` with a reference to a local, as long as it outlives `seq`. In your experiments you probably didn't use `as_mut()`, without which the `unwrap()` moves `seq` out of the option. That leads to another "doesn't live long enough" error, seemingly defeating the longer-scoped `seq` in a very confusing manner. The  fix is trivial, but only once you understand the source of the problem.

Comment: @user4815162342 You're correct, I didn't realize `as_mut().unwrap()` would avoid moving the data out of the `Option`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `ser` doesn't get dropped prematurely by declaring it outside the if body:

```rust
let mut ser;
let mut seq = if output {
    let out = std::io::stdout();
    ser = serde_json::Serializer::new(out);
    let seq = ser.serialize_seq(None)?;
    Some(Ok(seq))
} else {
    None
}.transpose()?;
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe that works. I didn't know rust allowed declaration without assignment like that, though I see it's perfectly safe.